# Download image from iCloud Drive iOS objective C

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, icloud-drive

I have gone through many links, but nothing worked for me. All i need to do is fetch all iCloud Drive files and download images. I succeeded fetching all files using below code

```
 - (void)presentDocumentPicker {
    NSArray *documentTypes = @[@"public.content", @"public.text", @"public.source-code ", @"public.image", @"public.audiovisual-content", @"com.adobe.pdf", @"com.apple.keynote.key", @"com.microsoft.word.doc", @"com.microsoft.excel.xls", @"com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt"];


    UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPickerViewController = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:documentTypes inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeOpen];
    documentPickerViewController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:documentPickerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


#pragma mark - UIDocumentPickerDelegate

- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self.documentURL = url;

    QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
    previewController.delegate = self;
    previewController.dataSource = self;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:previewController animated:YES];
}
```

now i don't know how to proceed further to download image.

Comment: what is issue while downloading images?

Comment: i need guideline from the very first step, as i have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to download images using this

```
    #pragma mark - UIDocumentPickerDelegate
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self.documentURL = url;


    NSNumber *isDownloadedValue = NULL;

    BOOL success = [url getResourceValue:&isDownloadedValue forKey: NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadingKey error:NULL];

    if (success && ![isDownloadedValue boolValue]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:url error:nil];

        // load image from Ubiquity Documents directory
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
           UIImage *     image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }

    QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
    previewController.delegate = self;
    previewController.dataSource = self;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:previewController animated:YES];
}
```