# Get file list from iCloud Drive iOS Objective c

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-drive

i was able to download the images from iCloud Drive implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809076/download-image-from-icloud-drive-ios-objective-c), but now i need to get all the files list from the iCloud Drive, but i am unable to fetch the list, i also tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622062/how-do-i-tell-ios-to-download-a-file-from-icloud-drive-and-get-progress-feedback), but it does not return any NSMetadataQuery results, any help would be helpful.

Comment: Did you found the way?

Comment: @PraveenKumar  There's no access to the list of files from iCloud...only way is to use default controller